How-to use tm4e to add vsCode LSP autocomplete brackets to Eclipse
PLEASE help me to get autocomplete braces and brackets working for this vsCode configuration:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thqby.vscode-autohotkey2-lsp
I am relatively non-technical.
I enjoy using eclipse for simple java programs.
What I've tried:  Installed tm4e
Under preferences, defined a file association for *.ahk as generic text editor.
I added this to the top section of the file:  ahk2.tmLanguage.json
"fileTypes": [
"ah2",
"ahk"
],
preferences -> TextMate, Under grammar, I tnen used the file in the Add dialog box and it seemed to accept it, but does not put it into the list.
Likewise, I tried to add to the syntaxes list using the file: ahk2.configuration.json
Ithen restarted eclipse and created a new file file.ahk or file.ah2  but there is no obvious autocomplete.
I also want auto-indent to work.
Please walk me through the correct steps.
Thank you Larry S

See https://github-wiki-see.page/m/angelozerr/eclipse-articles/wiki/tm4e

HELP, Please tell me how to add the tmLanguage and language configuration files so that the content type will actually show up in the respective TextMate dialog boxes and so that the editor will actually begin to auto-complete etc.  That link does not do the job.

"That link does not do the job." - Please tell exactly where you get stuck. "I added this to the top section of the file..." - Why did you do that? What instructions did you follow? The grammar is for syntax highlighting, the language configuration is for autocomplete brackets, etc.: in the preferences TextMate > Language Configurations. Be aware that not all grammars are supported. Grammars with regular expressions containing look behind of indefinite length do not work. For autocomplete brackets start with an existing working grammar and edit the language configuration.
